# Python - detect elements of a region

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an array made of 1 and 0 (image below), and I am working on a Python script that detects the borders of the central region (the big white blob) and marks all the internal points as 1. How would you do it?

I wrote a piece of code that does repeated connectivity search, but this doesn't seem the way to go - the region changes shape and new areas are added.

[image]

Comment: Do you need the exact outline of the region? What about filling the "holes" in it? Search for "segmentation" algorithms. With problems like these there is often no right answer, and you'll need to decide what trade-offs you're willing to make.

Comment: Connected component labeling might be what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks I will follow your tips and update with my progresses

Comment: Connected components labaling, to get the regions separeted. Counts id's to get the biggest one, and then floodfill if you want to fill the holes. That should work i think. Opencv is a good library for this.

Comment: This is just the classic image segmentation problem with noise. Lots of libraries provide connected component solutions or library versions of things like Mumford-Shah functional minimization techniques. You may also just simply pass a local median filter over your data several times and see if that boosts the simple connected component method well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I can't put a comment i put it here.

I had a problem close to yours: I wanted to select several holes and then calculate the area, the roundness...

What I did was to use the java implementation of python (jython) by which I could use a library called imageJ which is dedicated to image processing (all is include in Fiji). Navigating in the library is a bit fastidiuous but it is powerfull one

Here is the wand tool: http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/gui/Wand.html
Have a look here for "How getting pixels of a ROi" : http://fiji.sc/Introduction_into_Developing_Plugins#ImageJ.27s_API

Comment: Doesn't PIL have the same functionality, and I believe it is native to Python

Comment: Maybe but I've never use it! Albus you should be aware that my solution i not "simple" but it does the trick and it is use to large pictures (maybe PIL too of course!)